# yum update reports errors on EC2 on package dependency

Tags: amazon-ec2

Performing `yum update -y` on EC2 reports errors below

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker.x86_64 0:18.06.1ce-10.amzn2 will be updated
---> Package docker.x86_64 0:18.09.9ce-2.amzn2 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: runc = 1.0.0 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: containerd = 1.2.6 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_64
---> Package jenkins.noarch 0:2.208-1.1 will be updated
---> Package jenkins.noarch 0:2.209-1.1 will be an update
---> Package libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-15.amzn2 will be updated
---> Package libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-21.amzn2 will be an update
---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.3.1-3.amzn2.0.3 will be updated
---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.4.1-1.amzn2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.10-3.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I could potentially perform workaround as suggested but I am inclined not to as I want always a clean update.

Some additional information:

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
repo id                                               repo name                                                status
!amzn2-core/2/x86_64                                  Amazon Linux 2 core repository                           17,916
amzn2extra-ansible2/2/x86_64                          Amazon Extras repo for ansible2                              47
amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64                            Amazon Extras repo for docker                                19
docker-ce-stable/x86_64                               Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                    63
epel-apache-maven/x86_64                              maven from apache foundation.                                 4
jenkins                                               Jenkins                                                     537
```

I did

> yum clean all

But still no charm

Unable to find package container-selinux on EC2 as well

```
 sudo yum whatprovides container-selinux
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core/2/x86_64/filelists_db                                                              |  31 MB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-ansible2/2/x86_64/filelists_db                                                     | 264 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64/filelists_db                                                       |  10 kB  00:00:00
docker-ce-stable/x86_64/filelists_db                                                          |  18 kB  00:00:00
epel-apache-maven/x86_64/filelists_db                                                         | 4.6 kB  00:00:00
jenkins/filelists_db                                                                          |  91 kB  00:00:00
No matches found
```

subscription-manager  reports command not found..

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
-bash: subscription-manager: command not found
```

Any idea any clues, or this should be raised as a Ticket with AWS?

Comment: i have same problem